# Interacting with Google's Geolocation Detection

Tags: google-maps, geolocation

I have two issues with Google's location detection.
I am using the basic code of this example:
http://code.google.com/intl/de-DE/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-geolocation.html

1.) When a visitor declines his location to be detected, then the map will not show. That cripples the site. How can I show a **fallback map** with standard functionality and without location detection?

2.) Is there a way to **interact with the result of the browser dialogue** that asks the viewer to detect his location? If a viewer declines his location to be detected and if the above point 1.) is not possible, then it would be good to hide the map alltogether.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `else` part of the `handleNoGeolocation` function you would provide your fallback code giving a default location or another means of location detection.

Here's an alternative structure for the functions that's a little drier and uses Google's IP geolocation for fallback:

```
if (navigator.geolocation) {
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(updatePosition, ipPosition, { options... });
} else {
  ipPosition();
}

function ipPosition() {
  updatePosition(google.loader.ClientLocation);
}

function updatePosition(position) {
  if (position == null) {
    return updatePosition(defaultPlace());
  }

  // Firefox 3.6 passes in a non-standard position object with lat/lng at the top level instead of in .coords
  var coords = (position.hasOwnProperty("coords")) ? position.coords : position;
  if (coords == null) {
    return updatePosition(defaultPlace());
  }

  [...]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In that sample there is a function `handleNoGeolocation` that they use when the user don't have or declines positioning. With the same technique you should be able to handle the hiding of the map.

Comment: Yes. But the map stays blank if people deny the location detection.